# Show that for each of the following graphs G there exists up to isomorphism precisely one category A with G(A) = G.

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory

I was working through the exercises in Abstract and Concrete Categories: The Joy of Cats (http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf) and I was stuck on exercise 3A.(d).

It seems to me that the graphs in question do not determine a unique category up to isomorphism, since there is ambiguity in how to compose the endomorphisms which aren't the identity. I was hoping somebody could help me understand why these graphs correspond to unique (up to isomorphism) categories.

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer to your question at all, but I'm interested in giving that pdf a read - what are the prerequisites for it?

Comment: @Irregular User: From the introduction: "... The only formal prerequisite for the reader is an elementary knowledge of set theory. However, an additional acquaintance with some algebra, topology, or computer science will be helpful, since concepts and results in the text are illustrated by various examples from these fields..."

Comment: @JohannesHuisman Thanks - not sure how I missed that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me show you how to do the first graph; the second graph uses similar ideas but is more complicated.  Let's let $X$ and $Y$ be the two objects, with $f:X\to Y$, $g:Y\to X$, and $h:Y\to Y$ the non-identity morphisms.  The only compositions that are not automatically determined are $fg$ and $h^2$: each of them could be either $h$ or $1_Y$.  Note that $gf:X\to X$ must be $1_X$, since there are no non-identity morphisms $X\to X$.  Now if $fg$ were $1_Y$, then $f$ and $g$ would be inverse isomorphisms, so $X\cong Y$.  This is impossible, since there is a nonidentity morphism $Y\to Y$ but not a non-identity morphism $X\to X$.  (Explicitly, note that $ghf=1_X$ and so if $fg=1_Y$, then $h=1_Yh1_Y=(fg)h(fg)=f(ghf)g=f(1_X)g=fg=1_Y$, which is a contradiction.)

Thus $fg\neq 1_Y$, so $fg=h$.  The only composition that remains to be determined is $h^2$.  But since $fg=h$, $$h^2=(fg)(fg)=f(gf)g=f1_Xg=fg=h.$$  So we have determined the entire composition operation for our category, and so it is unique up to isomorphism.

Comment: I think that at the end of the first paragraph you meant to say that $h = 1_Y h 1_Y$ and not $h = 1_Y h 1_X$, but minor typo notwithstanding this was a really helpful answer. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, yes, I'll fix that.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction for the second graph as well?

Comment: Let $e$ and $f$ be the two arrows from left to right and $g$ be the arrow from right to left.  Try showing that one of the loops must be equal to $fg$ and the other must be equal to $eg$.  A fact that you'll use repeatedly is that the only map from the object on the left to itself is the identity.